live server in vs code opens the html file as a listing directory
I have been using vs code for html and recently when i open the code with live server in chrom it opens a listing directory instead of the website i made , and i have tried to fix it from the command pallet but still didn't work

Whats the URL its trying to navigate to and whats the URL you see in the address bar in Chrome?

please use index.html as main file in your project it will automatically redirect to chrome as main page
